# How to judge which constructor is used in java, or how to know how many parameter does an instance have?

Tags: java, constructor

I have this class:

```
public class Function{
    private String name;
    public Function(){
    }
    public Function(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So what if I have two instances of this class, let's call them `ins1` and `ins2`. So how can I know which constructor did they use?

Comment: Why would you need to know that?

Comment: If there is no remaining code which consists of setters/getters, 'name' cant be initialized. Thus you can understand that the instance which has null 'name' has used empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case the instance that was created with the constructor `Function()` will return null for the member `name` because is not initialized...

the other instance has the field name initialized and using its getter you can check if it is null referenced or not.